# Move the Value against name from one Excel file to Other File against their name

Tags: vlookup

**1-** Hi I have two Excel file - Ist is Daily Process & IInd is Daily Order 
2- In Ist sheet there is name of 10 Person.there is 5 Column,
3- In Ist Column - S Empty & merged, IInd Column :- Rank, IIrd - Person name, 4th Column : Goal & In 5th Column : Order Value (which is empty, need to fillup from other sheet)

**4-** In IInd (Daily Order Eccel File) : There is 6 Column 
1st Column : Empty, 2nd Column : Person name 3rd Column : Goal, 4th Column : Carryover, 5thn Column : Receive Order & 6th Column (F) : Total Order

**5** From 6th Column i.e. F column, which is Total, i have to pick up this value against Person name (available here & also in Ist file Daily Process)

I have to put the formula in Ist File (I need value here against his name)

So please tell me the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,'Daily Order 2'!$B$1:$F$11,5,0)
```

in E2 of Daily Process and copied down to suit.